# TypeScript Clientside usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

I am in the process of migrating my project from JavaScript to TypeScript, so far everything went according to plan, but now I encountered a problem.
On the server side the TypeScript files are seen as modules, due to the use of import {controller} from "module" for example.
On the server side this is not an obstacle.
But now I'm wondering how I can use my types on the client side as well, for example the User.ts class - this can be used on the server side part without any problems. How can I use this client-side, since importing modules is not supported so far?

Are there any ways to achieve this without using Webpack or Browserify or similar?

Comment: There are alternatives to Browserify and Webpack, but you will need some tool or other